# transaction would cause overdraft

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity-0.8.x, mainnet

I am only borrowing 25% of my wallet balance and I get *transaction would cause overdraft* on Main net. The code works on Sepolia test net.

Any ideas of what causes this?

I get an instance

```
fromDexInstance, err := api.NewSwap(fromDexAddress, connection.Get())
```

From

```
// NewSwap creates a new instance of Swap, bound to a specific deployed contract.
func NewSwap(address common.Address, backend bind.ContractBackend) (*Swap, error) {
    contract, err := bindSwap(address, backend, backend, backend)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Swap{SwapCaller: SwapCaller{contract: contract}, SwapTransactor: SwapTransactor{contract: contract}, SwapFilterer: SwapFilterer{contract: contract}}, nil
}
```

The swap function

```
    swapTx, err := fromDexInstance.Swap(auth, assetAddress, loanAmount, common.HexToAddress(constants.FlashLoanAddress), fromDexAddress, toDexAddress) //nolint:lll
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err // <--transaction would cause overdraft
}
```

This is my Solidity contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import { IUniswapV2Pair } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Factory } from "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import { IUniswapV2Router02 } from "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {
    string public constant name = "ERC20Basic";
    string public constant symbol = "ERC";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 totalSupply_ = 10 ether;

    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner]-numTokens;
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender]+numTokens;
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}

contract Swap {
    event AssetSold(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event AssetBought(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event EtherReceived(address sender, uint amount);
    event LogMessage(string message);
    event LogMessages(string message, string message2);
    address private owner;
    address private _currentRouter0;
    address private _currentRouter1;
    address private _token;

    constructor() payable{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function _log(string memory message) private {
        emit LogMessage(message);
    }

    function swap(address token, uint256 ethToBorrow,  address tokenPairedWithWeth, address routerAddress0, address routerAddress1) public payable onlyOwner {
        _currentRouter0 = routerAddress0;
        _currentRouter1 = routerAddress1;
        _token = token;
        require(token != tokenPairedWithWeth, "Can't borrow ETH from the same pair as the one you're trading");
        address weth = IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).WETH();
        address pairWeth = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).factory()).getPair(weth, tokenPairedWithWeth);
        require(pairWeth != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router0");
        // Make sure the pools exist on both routers
        address pairAddress0 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress0).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
        require(pairAddress0 != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router0");
        address pairAddress1 = IUniswapV2Factory(IUniswapV2Router02(routerAddress1).factory()).getPair(token, weth);
        require(pairAddress1 != address(0), "This pool does not exist on router1");
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(pairWeth).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(pairWeth).token1();
        uint256 amount0 = weth == token0 ? ethToBorrow : 0;
        uint256 amount1 = weth == token1 ? ethToBorrow : 0;
        IUniswapV2Pair(pairWeth).swap(amount0, amount1, address(this), bytes("not empty"));

        _currentRouter0 = address(0);
        _currentRouter1 = address(0);
        _token = address(0);
    }

    function uniswapV2Call(address, uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1, bytes calldata) external {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token0();
        address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();

        IUniswapV2Router02 router0 = IUniswapV2Router02(_currentRouter0);
        IUniswapV2Router02 router1 = IUniswapV2Router02(_currentRouter1);

        require(msg.sender == IUniswapV2Factory(router0.factory()).getPair(token0, token1), "Unauthorized");

        require(amount0 == 0 || amount1 == 0, "Invalid amounts");

        path[0] = router1.WETH();
        path[1] = _token;

        IERC20 wethContract = IERC20(path[0]);
        IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(path[1]);
        uint256 wethBorrowed = wethContract.balanceOf(address(this));
        wethContract.approve(_currentRouter1, wethBorrowed);

        // Buy Token with WETH on Router 1 (where it's cheaper)
        uint256 tokensReceived = router1.swapExactTokensForTokens(wethBorrowed, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp)[1];

        // Sell Token for WETH on Router 0 (where it's more expensive)
        tokenContract.approve(_currentRouter0, tokensReceived);
        address path1 = path[0];
        path[0] = path[1]; // Reverse path
        path[1] = path1;
        uint256 wethReceived = router0.swapExactTokensForTokens(tokensReceived, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp)[1];

        uint256 profit = wethReceived > wethBorrowed ? wethReceived - wethBorrowed : 0;
        require(wethReceived > wethBorrowed, "Not enough to reimburse loan");

        wethContract.transfer(msg.sender, wethBorrowed);         
        wethContract.transfer(tx.origin, profit);
    }

    function updateOwner(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        owner = _newOwner;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit EtherReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function getRemainingGas() public view returns (uint256) {
        return gasleft();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming from a standard check in `go-ethereum`.

When submitting a new transaction, the node will check if the sender has other txs currently pending in the txpool. If yes, it will add up the gas cost + transaction value (amount of ETH being transferred if any) for all the pending txs + the tx being submitted. If the total is higher than the sender's balance, it gets rejected with `transaction would cause overdraft`.

I suspect you have prior transaction(s) stuck in the txpool, and sorting this out should solve the issue.